# How can I add another condition to my search query in mongoose.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
User.find({problem_no:1})
.count()
.exec(function (err, count) {
    res.send({user_problem_no_1: count})
})
```

Above is my query and it counts all the entries in my collection that says `problem_no` has a value `1`. I want to include here also verification of a date, so that I want to count only entries where `problem_no == 1` and that `created_at` is greater or equal `someDate`. How should I modify this query to perform it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one with [`$gte`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/gte/#op._S_gte)

```
User.find({problem_no:1, create_at: {$gte: someDate}})
```

Or with [`gte()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-gte)

```
User.find({problem_no:1}).where('create_at').gte(someDate)...
```

Answer (score 0):

with and you can do this

```
   User.find()
    .and([
      {problem_no: 1},
      {'created_at': date}} // i think in millieseconds
    ])
    .sort({created_at: -1})
    .exec(function (err, user) {
      // do stuff
    }
```